# How to check whether a variable is a class or not?

Tags: python, oop

I was wondering how to check whether a variable is a class (not an instance!) or not.

I've tried to use the function `isinstance(object, class_or_type_or_tuple)` to do this, but I don't know what type a class would have.

For example, in the following code

```
class Foo:
    pass

isinstance(Foo, **???**) # i want to make this return True.
```

I tried to substitute  "`class`" with **???**, but I realized that `class` is a keyword in python.

Comment: In Python 3, the `???` equals to `type`. See also: [inspect.isclass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f01f77f8fabcfd7ddb5d99f12d6fc99af9af384/Lib/inspect.py#L191) implementation.

Answer (score 493, accepted):

Even better: use the [`inspect.isclass`](https://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.isclass) function.

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class X(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.isclass(X)
True

>>> x = X()
>>> isinstance(x, X)
True
>>> inspect.isclass(x)
False
```

Comment: If you also want `inspect.isclass` to return `True` if the object to inspect is a *class instance*, use `inspect.isclass(type(Myclass()))`

Comment: @michaelmeyer `type(whatever)` always returns an object that is a class, so this check is redundant. If it didn't there would be no way to instantiate `whatever` and thus you couldn't perform the check in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Using python3 with snakemake, `type(snakemake.utils)` returns `<class 'module'>` and yet `inspect.isclass(snakemake.utils)` returns `False`.

Comment: That's because `snakemake.util` is a module not a class?

Comment: @tedtoal `type(snakemake.utils)` returning `<class 'module'>` means `snakemake.utils` is an _object_ of class _module_. So `isclass()` behavior is correct.

Comment: As of this writing, in the [`inspect.py`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f01f77f8fabcfd7ddb5d99f12d6fc99af9af384/Lib/inspect.py#L191) module of the python standard library, the `isclass(object)` function is a one-liner: `return isinstance(object, type)`.

Comment: It's true that `inspect.isclass` was more useful in Python 2, where there were old and new-style classes to worry about. Perhaps the one remaining advantage of that function is that the intent is very clear.

Answer (score 71):

```
>>> class X(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> type(X)
<type 'type'>
>>> isinstance(X,type)
True
```

Comment: Hm... Nice answer, but when i do type(Foo) on my Foo class, it says <type 'classobj'> instead of <type 'type'>. I assume that the diference comes from the fact that X is inheriting from the object, but Foo isn't. Is there any other difference arising from this? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work for old-style classes: `'class Old:pass' 'isinstance(Old, type) == False'`, but `inspect.isclass(Old) == True`.

Comment: @jeeyoungk: You're not "assuming the difference comes from...", you're actually reading that in the code.  A subclass of object ("new style") has the desired properties, just what you see here.

Comment: Here's the hint -- since this works for new-style classes, don't use old-style classes.  There's no point to using old-style classes.

Comment: isinstance(e, f)  E is the instantiated object, F is the class object.

Comment: This won't work if your class X has a metaclass. If it has a metaclass, then the metaclass will be returned rather than type.

Comment: By the way, all classes are new-style in Python 3 - there is no classobj, so this is better than importing inspect just to check if variable is class.

Answer (score 54):

The inspect.isclass is probably the best solution, and it's really easy to see how it's actually implemented

```
def isclass(obj):
    """Return true if the obj is a class.

    Class objects provide these attributes:
        __doc__         documentation string
        __module__      name of module in which this class was defined"""
    return isinstance(obj, (type, types.ClassType))
```

Comment: remember `import types`

Comment: `types.ClassType` is no longer needed in Python 3 (and is removed).

Comment: this doesn't work with new style classes at all.... even in python 2.   dont use this solution alone

Comment: That was taken from the inspect module so I doubt it doesn't work.
It's simple to check with Python2.7 for example
`In [8]: class NewStyle(object):
       ...:     pass
       ...: 

    In [9]: isinstance(NewStyle, (type, types.ClassType))
    Out[9]: True`

Comment: This is the Python 2 implementation, which has to handle old-style and new-style classes. Python 3 simplifies this to `isinstance(object, type)`. Note that objects like `int`, `list`, `str`, etc. are **also** classes, so you can't use this to distinguish between *custom classes defined in Python* and *built-in classes defined in C code*.

Comment: Don't call your argument `object`. That shadows the prominent built-in name `object`.

Comment: interesting to have so many upvotes for something that is so incorrect now, regardless of how well it worked before:  **this DOESNT WORK on Python 3**.

Comment: @JLPeyret The code shown - demonstrating an implementation of `inspect.isclass` - doesn't work, but `inspect.isclass` still does. The implementation changed.

Answer (score 45):

```
isinstance(X, type)
```

Return `True` if `X` is class and `False` if not.

Comment: I get False, even if X is a class.

Comment: This only works for new style classes.  Old style classes are of type 'classobj'.  So if you're using old style classes you can do:
import types
isinstance(X, types.ClassType)

Comment: This appears to be the same as [`S. Lott's answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/395741/208880), which is four years older.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for Python 3, as all classes are "new style" classes there. See also [inspect.isclass](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f01f77f8fabcfd7ddb5d99f12d6fc99af9af384/Lib/inspect.py#L191) implementation, which is exactly this. One line. No need to import anything.

Answer (score 7):

This check is compatible with both Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

```
import six
isinstance(obj, six.class_types)
```

This is basically a wrapper function that performs the same check as in andrea_crotti answer.

Example:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> isinstance(datetime.date, six.class_types)
>>> True
>>> isinstance(datetime.date.min, six.class_types)
>>> False
```

Answer (score 4):

Benjamin Peterson is correct about the use of `inspect.isclass()` for this job.
But note that you can test if a `Class` object is a specific `Class`, and therefore implicitly a `Class`, using the built-in function [issubclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#issubclass).
Depending on your use-case this can be more pythonic.

```
from typing import Type, Any
def isclass(cl: Type[Any]):
    try:
        return issubclass(cl, cl)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

Can then be used like this:

```
>>> class X():
...     pass
... 
>>> isclass(X)
True
>>> isclass(X())
False
```

Comment: This `Type[Any]` seems wrong: if the function were indeed expecting a `Type[Any]` it wouldn’t need the `try`/`except`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I found and use successfully is:

```py
 def isclass(cls):
    return str(type(cls)).startswith("<class") and hasattr(cls, '__weakref__')
```

Comment: Your approach might not work in all cases: the `__weakref__` attribute is automatically added to instances of user-defined classes that inherit from object and do not explicitly set `__slots__` without including `__weakref__`. This attribute allows the object to be weakly referable, meaning you can create weak references to the object without increasing its reference count.

Answer (score 1):

class Foo: is called old style class and class X(object): is called new style class.

Check this [What is the difference between old style and new style classes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) . New style is recommended. Read about "[unifying types and classes](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/)"

Comment: This should have been a comment perhaps?

Comment: In addition to this maybe should have been a comment, the information is outdated. In Python 3, while `class Foo(object): ...` is equivalent to `class Foo: ...` this [answer on why one would inherit from object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45062077/2364215)

Answer (score 1):

simplest way is to use `inspect.isclass` as posted in the most-voted answer.
the implementation details could be found at [python2 inspect](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py) and [python3 inspect](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/inspect.py).
for new-style class: `isinstance(object, type)`
for old-style class: `isinstance(object, types.ClassType)`
em, for old-style class, it is using `types.ClassType`, here is the code from [types.py](https://github.com/enthought/Python-2.7.3/blob/master/Lib/types.py#L51:1):

```
class _C:
    def _m(self): pass
ClassType = type(_C)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `inspect.isclass` is not working for me, instead, try this

```py
class foo:
    pass

var = foo()

if str(type(var)).split(".")[0] == "<class '__main__":
    print("this is a class")
else:
    print(str(type(var)).split(".")[0])
```

So basically, `type(var)` is `<class 'a type'>`

Example: `<class 'int'`
But, when `var` is a class, it will appear something like `<class '__main__.classname'>`

So we split the string into `<class '__main__` and we compare using `if`, if the string fit perfectly then it's a class

[image]

Comment: I don't think i got any vote lol

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a class decorator, `inspect.isclass()` will not work since the class is wrapped by a function. Instead, use `inspect.unwrap()` first, then test with `inspect.isclass()`.

**Example:**

```
import functools
import inspect

def class_decorator(cls):
    @functools.wraps(cls)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return cls(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@class_decorator
class Spam:
    pass

print(inspect.isclass(Spam)) # False
print(type(Spam)) # class 'function'

print(inspect.isclass(inspect.unwrap(Spam))) # True
print(inspect.unwrap(Spam)) # class 'Spam'
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an alternative way to check it:

```
import inspect

class cls():
     print(None)

inspect.isclass(cls)
```

Reference: https://www.kite.com/python/docs/inspect.isclass

Comment: Why add a new answer about `inspect.isclass`? This duplicates Benjamin Peterson’s answer.

Answer (score -1):

In some cases (depending on your system), a simple test is to see if your variable has a __module__ attribute.

```
if getattr(my_variable,'__module__', None):
    print(my_variable, ".__module__ is ",my_variable.__module__)
else:
    print(my_variable,' has no __module__.')
```

int, float, dict, list, str etc do not have __module__

Answer (score -2):

There are some working solutions here already, but here's another one:

```
>>> import types
>>> class Dummy: pass
>>> type(Dummy) is types.ClassType
True
```

Comment: `types.ClassType` was removed in Python 3