# What is the naming convention for Python class references

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pep8

What is the naming convention for a variable referencing a class in Python?

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

# which one is correct?
reference_to_class = MyClass

# or
ReferenceToClass = MyClass
```

Here is another example that resembles my situation:

```
# cars.py
class Car(object):
    pass

class Sedan(Car):
    pass

class Coupe(Car):
    pass

class StatonWagon(Car):
    pass

class Van(Car):
    pass

def get_car_class(slug, config):
    return config.get(slug)

# config.py
CONFIG = {
    'ford-mustang': Coupe,
    'buick-riviera': Coupe,
    'chevrolet-caprice': Sedan,
    'chevy-wan' Van:
    'ford-econoline': Van
}

# main.py
from config.py import CONFIG
from cars import get_car_class

MyCarClass = get_car_class('buick-riviera')

my_car = MyCarClass()
```

I would prefer ReferenceToClass, that everybody new to the code knows it's a class and not an instance. But as [poplitea wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765980/what-is-the-naming-convention-for-python-class-references#comment18923309_13766060), literature reference would be great.

Comment: ReferenceToClass is exactly the same as MyClass here (semantically). Both are variables that refer to the same class object.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On module level the second:

`ReferenceToClass = MyClass`

As a function argument, the first:

`reference_to_class = MyClass`

Comment: Any literature references?

Comment: pep8 http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/. An alias to the class behaves exactly like the class, so it's naming should adhere to the same scheme as normal class naming, I think.

Comment: As a function argument, the first, mainly because you cannot know for sure you'll actually get a descandant of type (i.e. a class).

Comment: meaning for `second` and `first` depends on the text of the question. probably a good idea to write explicit texts in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

**tl;dr**: for global/public names use `AllCaps` like [XORcist said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13766060/4298200):

```
class Logger:
    pass

AliasLogger = Logger
```

For function parameters and function locals, make it clear that you are dealing with the class object with a descriptive name like this:

```
def some_func(logger_class):
    pass
```

or something along the lines

```
def some_func(my_class_classobj):
    pass
```

when the word `"class"` is actually in your classname. For `classobj`, see also `class_` and `klass`.

---

**Analysis/Motivation** (long version)

No thorough reading, but at a glance [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) doesn't seem to be explicit on this (neither google's python style guide for that matter).

Since a variable name is probably just yet-another [name binding](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) in python, in my opinion it doesn't really matter whether you bind that name with the definition block or later with the `=` equal sign to some object.

For this I agree with [XORcist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13766060/611007) in that module level "alias" references should adhere to your class naming standard, probably AllCaps:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

# good
ReferenceToClass = MyClass
```

However when it comes to parameter and variable names, supposedly `lowercase_underscores` should apply, right? I'm unhappy with only that, since it will push you into the instance vs class reference ambiguity. There is the potential that an all-lowercase name may be an attempt to hint the object being an instance. For that matter, I recommend postfixing your all-lowercase, class-referencing variable names with the "class" suffix, like this:

```
class Logger(object):
    pass

def function_expecting_class_reference(logger_class):
    pass
```

I renamed your example class `MyClass` to `Logger` because in real scenarios only a few class name contains the string `"class"`. However in that latter case I propose to avoid the ambiguity with descriptive naming yet again. For example, you may use a `classobj` suffix:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

def function_expecting_class_reference(another_param, my_class_classobj):
    ReferenceToClass = MyClass
```

Another alternative I tend to take is to use the suffix `klass`, like `my_class_klass`. Not everyone seems to get the latter, but anyway I'm yet to test whether they would get the former any better.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the suffix.  I often use a "_ref" suffix to clarify and improve code readability when assigning a variable to an object reference.

Comment: What about `cls`?

Answer (score 2):

I treat it the same as an instance variable, which PEP8 defines as using lowercase_underscore_style. (lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.)

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id34