# The functionality of isinstance(...); but without an instance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, types

At runtime, I want to check whether a specified child class is derived from a specified parent class.

With an object instance, it's easy:

```py
def is_related(child_instance, parent_type):
    return isinstance(child_instance, parent_type)
```

Is there some way to do this without having (or creating) an instance of the child but, instead, having a reference to the child's type?

Something like...

```py
def is_related(child_type, parent_type):
    return is_child_class(child_type, parent_type)
```

Provide an implementation for `is_child_class` will answer this question.

(By comparison, types in C# know about their supertypes. I don't know whether this is also true in Python.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check (at runtime) if one class is a subclass of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912972/how-do-i-check-at-runtime-if-one-class-is-a-subclass-of-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that `ChildClass` is a subclass of `ParentClass`. Then

```
issubclass(ChildClass, ParentClass)
```

would return `True`

Comment: Your answer came in seconds before @RiccardoBucco's. Thanks to you both!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible solution:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

issubclass(B, A) # True
```

Comment: Thanks, @RiccardoBucco. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need to define the `is_child_class` method as:

```
def is_child_class(child_type, parent_type):
  return issubclass(child_type, parent_type)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer.