# Why does isinstance not recognize io.BytesIO as a subclass of io.IOBase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

**EDIT: It was my bad. I should have used `issubclass` instead of `isinstance`, as suggested in @kevin-mayo 's answer. Then everything works.**

I recently stumbled upon a weird behaviour of pycharm's type hinting, which later revealed a trouble with python itself. I have a method which takes a stream, so I set the type as `io.BaseIO`. However, when I passed a `BytesIO` to it, it gave me a warning. I checked the following:

```
>>> io.BytesIO.__mro__
(<class '_io.BytesIO'>, <class '_io._BufferedIOBase'>, <class '_io._IOBase'>, <class 'object'>)
>>> isinstance(io.BytesIO, io.IOBase)
False
```

This contradicts what Python docs say, so I'm really confused.

I'm using Python 3.7.

I realize the duck typing way of doing this, but keep in mind that I'm not making a strict type check, but a convenient type hint.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of [How do I check (at runtime) if one class is a subclass of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912972/how-do-i-check-at-runtime-if-one-class-is-a-subclass-of-another)

Comment: @mkrieger1 The question isn't really a duplicate, but rather useless to anyone but me, since it was my personal dumb mistake. I can't seem to find a button to close my own question, but I can delete it if I should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because

```
isinstance(io.BytesIO, io.IOBase)
```

is to check whether it is the instance of the class,

You may need to use `issubclass(io.BytesIO, io.IOBase)` to check them

Comment: OMG, You're right. I'm so dumb). So that makes it pycharm glitch, but I suppose I can live with that)

Comment: @abel1502 I think the cause is `pycharm` doesn't know the type of your variable due to python is a dynamic language, You could use annotation to let pycharm "think" it is a `IOBase`.Or you could try a useful plugin called `Kite`.

Comment: @Kite, no, it did know the type - it said something like "BytesIO passed where IOBase was expected". + The code was like `stream = io.BytesIO()\nself.write(stream)`. But rebooting pycharm has actually fixed this as well