# What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method?

Tags: python, oop, function, methods

I'm asking this question because of a discussion on the comment thread of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11934332/1523776). I'm 90% of the way to getting my head round it.

```
In [1]: class A(object):  # class named 'A'
   ...:     def f1(self): pass
   ...:
In [2]: a = A()  # an instance
```

`f1` exists in three different forms:

```
In [3]: a.f1  # a bound method
Out[3]: <bound method a.f1 of <__main__.A object at 0x039BE870>>
In [4]: A.f1  # an unbound method
Out[4]: <unbound method A.f1>
In [5]: a.__dict__['f1']  # doesn't exist
KeyError: 'f1'
In [6]: A.__dict__['f1']  # a function
Out[6]: <function __main__.f1>
```

What is the difference between the *bound method*, *unbound method* and *function* objects, all of which are described by f1? How does one call these three objects? How can they be transformed into each other? The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) on this stuff is quite hard to understand.

Comment: Note that unbound methods are gone in Python 3, `C.f1` is the same function as `C.__dict__['f1']`.

Comment: This question's title is misleading as it's not as general as it suggests. Should be named *"How does the Python data model handle unbound methods, bound methods and function calls?"* *"How does one call these three objects?*: you don't call unbound methods directly; the Python data model does it for you. The answers don't even touch the main operational difference between `str.lower('Foo')` and `'Foo'.lower()` : the former is slower and unnecessary.

Comment: @smci comparing `import dis; dis.dis("str.lower('foo')")` and `import dis; dis.dis("'foo'.lower()")`, they are different by a single `LOAD_NAME` call out of 4 or 5 total calls.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/114214

Answer (score 86, accepted):

A *function* is created by the `def` statement, or by `lambda`.  Under Python 2, when a function appears within the body of a `class` statement (or is passed to a `type` class construction call), it is transformed into an *unbound method*.  (Python 3 doesn't have unbound methods; see below.)  When a function is accessed on a class instance, it is transformed into a *bound method*, that automatically supplies the instance to the method as the first `self` parameter.

```
def f1(self):
    pass
```

Here `f1` is a *function*.

```
class C(object):
    f1 = f1
```

Now `C.f1` is an unbound method.

```
>>> C.f1
<unbound method C.f1>
>>> C.f1.im_func is f1
True
```

We can also use the `type` class constructor:

```
>>> C2 = type('C2', (object,), {'f1': f1})
>>> C2.f1
<unbound method C2.f1>
```

We can convert `f1` to an unbound method manually:

```
>>> import types
>>> types.MethodType(f1, None, C)
<unbound method C.f1>
```

Unbound methods are bound by access on a class instance:

```
>>> C().f1
<bound method C.f1 of <__main__.C object at 0x2abeecf87250>>
```

Access is translated into calling through the descriptor protocol:

```
>>> C.f1.__get__(C(), C)
<bound method C.f1 of <__main__.C object at 0x2abeecf871d0>>
```

Combining these:

```
>>> types.MethodType(f1, None, C).__get__(C(), C)
<bound method C.f1 of <__main__.C object at 0x2abeecf87310>>
```

Or directly:

```
>>> types.MethodType(f1, C(), C)                
<bound method C.f1 of <__main__.C object at 0x2abeecf871d0>>
```

The main difference between a function and an unbound method is that the latter knows which class it is bound to; calling or binding an unbound method requires an instance of its class type:

```
>>> f1(None)
>>> C.f1(None)
TypeError: unbound method f1() must be called with C instance as first argument (got NoneType instance instead)
>>> class D(object): pass
>>> f1.__get__(D(), D)
<bound method D.f1 of <__main__.D object at 0x7f6c98cfe290>>
>>> C.f1.__get__(D(), D)
<unbound method C.f1>
```

Since the difference between a function and an unbound method is pretty minimal, Python 3 [gets rid of the distinction](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#operators-and-special-methods); under Python 3 accessing a function on a class instance just gives you the function itself:

```
>>> C.f1
<function f1 at 0x7fdd06c4cd40>
>>> C.f1 is f1
True
```

In both Python 2 and Python 3, then, these three are equivalent:

```
f1(C())
C.f1(C())
C().f1()
```

Binding a function to an instance has the effect of fixing its first parameter (conventionally called `self`) to the instance.  Thus the bound method `C().f1` is equivalent to either of:

```
(lamdba *args, **kwargs: f1(C(), *args, **kwargs))
functools.partial(f1, C())
```

Comment: so "bound" means a method is "bound to an instance", "unbound" means it isn't

Comment: This is where the _real_ answer should be revealed: _The main difference between a function and an unbound method is in the latter's support for the descriptor protocol; calling an unbound method requires an instance._ But what does this mean? A function doesn't support the descriptor protocol? It does, as `f1.__get__` also works.

Comment: @musiphil yes, that was wrong. The real  difference between a function and an unbound method is that the latter knows which class it is bound to; calling an unbound method requires an instance of its class type.

Comment: This answer could be improved with a comparison of Python 2 and Python 3's models of bound/unbound methods.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson done, cheers. Perhaps it could do with its own question.

Answer (score 10):

> is quite hard to understand

Well, it is quite a hard topic, and it has to do with descriptors.

Lets start with function.  Everything is clear here - you just call it, all supplied arguments are passed while executing it:

```
>>> f = A.__dict__['f1']
>>> f(1)
1
```

Regular `TypeError` is raised in case of any problem with number of parameters:

```
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f1() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Now, methods.  Methods are functions with a bit of spices.  Descriptors come in game here.  As described in [Data Model](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html), `A.f1` and `A().f1` are translated into `A.__dict__['f1'].__get__(None, A)` and `type(a).__dict__['f1'].__get__(a, type(a))` respectively.  And results of these `__get__`'s differ from the raw `f1` function.  These objects are wrappers around the original `f1` and contain some additional logic.

In case of `unbound method` this logic includes a check whether first argument is an instance of `A`:

```
>>> f = A.f1
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method f1() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> f(1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method f1() must be called with A instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

If this check succeeds, it executes original `f1` with that instance as first argument:

```
>>> f(A())
<__main__.A object at 0x800f238d0>
```

Note, that `im_self` attribute is `None`:

```
>>> f.im_self is None
True
```

In case of `bound method` this logic immediately supplies original `f1` with an instance of `A` it was created of (this instance is actually stored in `im_self` attribute):

```
>>> f = A().f1
>>> f.im_self
<__main__.A object at 0x800f23950>
>>> f()
<__main__.A object at 0x800f23950>
```

So, `bound` mean that underlying function is bound to some instance. `unbound` mean that it is still bound, but only to a class.

Answer (score 4):

A function object is a callable object created by a function definition. Both bound and unbound methods are callable objects created by a Descriptor called by the dot binary operator.

Bound and unbound method objects have 3 main properties: `im_func` is the function object defined in the class, `im_class` is the class, and `im_self` is the class instance. For unbound methods, `im_self` is `None`.

When a bound method is called, it calls `im_func` with `im_self` as the first parameter followed by its calling parameters. unbound methods call the underlying function with just its calling parameters.

Starting with Python 3, there are no unbound methods. `Class.method` returns a direct reference to the method.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) documentation for more details.

My interpretation is the following.

Class `Function` snippets:

Python 3:

```
class Function(object):
    . . .
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return types.MethodType(self, obj)
```

Python 2:

```
class Function(object):
    . . .
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        return types.MethodType(self, obj, objtype)
```

1. If a function is called without class or instance, it is a plain function.
2. If a function is called from a class or an instance, its `__get__` is called to retrieve wrapped function:
   a. `B.x` is same as `B.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, B)`.
   In Python 3, this returns plain function.
   In Python 2, this returns an unbound function.

   b. `b.x` is same as `type(b).__dict__['x'].__get__(b, type(b)`. This will return a bound method in both Python 2 and Python 3, which means `self` will be implicitly passed as first argument.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method?

From the ground breaking *what is a function* perspective there is no difference.
Python object oriented features are built upon a function based environment.

*Being bound* is equal to:

#### Will the function take the *class* (**cls**) or the *object instance* (**self**) as the first parameter or no?

Here is the example:

```
class C:

    #instance method 
    def m1(self, x):
        print(f"Excellent m1 self {self} {x}")

    @classmethod
    def m2(cls, x):
        print(f"Excellent m2 cls {cls} {x}")

    @staticmethod
    def m3(x):
        print(f"Excellent m3 static {x}")    

ci=C()
ci.m1(1)
ci.m2(2)
ci.m3(3)

print(ci.m1)
print(ci.m2)
print(ci.m3)
print(C.m1)
print(C.m2)
print(C.m3)
```

---

Outputs:

```
Excellent m1 self <__main__.C object at 0x000001AF40319160> 1
Excellent m2 cls <class '__main__.C'> 2
Excellent m3 static 3
<bound method C.m1 of <__main__.C object at 0x000001AF40319160>>
<bound method C.m2 of <class '__main__.C'>>
<function C.m3 at 0x000001AF4023CBF8>
<function C.m1 at 0x000001AF402FBB70>
<bound method C.m2 of <class '__main__.C'>>
<function C.m3 at 0x000001AF4023CBF8>
```

The output shows the static function `m3` will be never called *bound*.
`C.m2` is bound to the `C` class because we sent the `cls` parameter which is the class pointer.

`ci.m1` and `ci.m2` are both bound; `ci.m1` because we sent `self` which is a pointer to the instance, and `ci.m2` because the instance knows that the class is bound ;).

#### To conclude you can bound method to a class or to a class object, based on the first parameter the method takes. If method is not bound it can be called unbound.

---

Note that method may not be originally part of the class. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015405/5884955) answer from Alex Martelli for more details.

Answer (score 1):

One interesting thing I saw today is that, when I assign a function to a class member, it becomes an unbound method. Such as:

```
class Test(object):
    @classmethod
    def initialize_class(cls):
        def print_string(self, str):
            print(str)
        # Here if I do print(print_string), I see a function
        cls.print_proc = print_string
        # Here if I do print(cls.print_proc), I see an unbound method; so if I
        # get a Test object o, I can call o.print_proc("Hello")
```