# Calling lambda method defined in class scope (as a class attribute)

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, class-method

```
class _GhostLink(object):
    toGhost = lambda filename: False

class _Mod_AllowGhosting_All(_GhostLink):
    def _loop(self):
        # ...
        if self.__class__.toGhost(fileName) != oldGhost:...
```

produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bash\basher\mod_links.py", line 592, in Execute
    changed = self._loop()
  File "bash\basher\mod_links.py", line 587, in _loop
    if self.__class__.toGhost(fileName) != oldGhost:
TypeError: unbound method <lambda>() must be called with _Mod_AllowGhosting_All instance as first argument (got Path instance instead)
```

while passing an instance as in `if self.toGhost(fileName) != ...` results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bash\basher\mod_links.py", line 592, in Execute
    changed = self._loop()
  File "bash\basher\mod_links.py", line 587, in _loop
    if self.toGhost(fileName) != oldGhost:
TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

How come `toGhost` behaves as a <del>classmethod</del> instance method ?

EDIT: I know the difference of class,static etc methods - this is a syntactic question

Comment: Do you not want to use `@classmethod` on a `def to_ghost(...):`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method)

Comment: A `lambda` is no different than any other method definition inside a class body. Unless you mark it as a `@staticmethod` it will expect a `self` parameter.

Comment: @tzaman: yes for some reason the fact that I assign the method to a class attribute made me think it would itself be a "static" method

Comment: lambdas are anonymous functions and assigning them to variables like that is usually bad practice. You loose doc strings and decorators and generally cause others to scratch their heads wondering why you did it. Just use a `def` for named functions.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D That's not how it works in Python. When you look up *any* function as an attribute of a class instance, it tries to treat it like an instance method unless you explicitly tell it not to (that's what the `@staticmethod` decorator is for).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this happens is fundamentally that `lambda` and `def` do the same thing, except that `def` also assigns a variable,  That is, both constructs produce a function.

The binding of a function (whether from `lambda` or `def`) into an instance method happens because functions are also descriptors;  remember, in every single case:

```
foo = lambda (...): (...)
```

is identical to:

```
def foo(...):
    return (...)
```

so when you say:

```
class _GhostLink(object):
    toGhost = lambda filename: False
```

It's the same as if you had said:

```
class _GhostLink(object):
    def toGhost(filename): 
        return False
```

So the moral of the story is that you should probably *never* use `lambda` as the right side of an assignment; it's not "better" or even *different* from using `def`.  All it does is confuse.

Comment: Thanks for catching the real question - I had a difficulty phrasing it - now I know how I should refactor :)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you want a static method:

```
class _GhostLink(object):
    toGhost = staticmethod(lambda filename: False)
```

or:

```
class _GhostLink(object):
    @staticmethod
    def toGhost(filename):
        return False
```

Comment: Yes I guessed so - but it still surprises me - I would expect the lambda to be a static method - how come it is interpreted as a instance method?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D You mean "instancemethod", not "classmethod" -- they're different. And the interpretation depends on how the method is looked up. Read up on the "descriptor protocol".

Comment: @tzaman: that's what I would like to see some clarifications on :)