# What is 'wrapped' by a python method wrapper

Tags: python, oop, python-internals

I'm reading through [this blog post on OOP in python 3](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2014/08/20/python-3-oop-part-2-classes-and-members/#.VuchD2GgrZ4). In it there is:

> As you can see, a `__get__` method is listed among the members of the function, and Python recognizes it as a method-wrapper. This method shall connect the open function to the door1 instance, so we can call it passing the instance alone.

I'm trying to understand this more intuitively. In this context what is 'wrapping' what?

[image]

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `method-wrapper` object is wrapping a C function. It binds together an instance (here a `function` instance, defined in a C struct) and a C function, so that when you call it, the right instance information is passed to the C function.

It is the C API equivalent of `method` objects and `function`s on a custom class. Given a class `Foo` with a function `bar`, `Foo().bar` produces a bound method, which combines together the `Foo()` instance and the `Foo.bar` function, so that when called, you can pass in that instance as the first argument (usually called `self`).

Also see the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html); this is what defines the `__get__` method and how it is invoked.

Comment: Thanks, So would it be fair to say___get___ 'wraps' a C-function, allowing python the ability to access its functionality?

Comment: Yes, with the understanding that it's purpose is to keep function and object together. No point in calling the C function without something to operate on.