# Id of class method and instance method changes for few seconds

Tags: python

I am curious how python class/instance  method connects

and I make a class with three methods (instance/class/static)

```
class Asian_loser(object):
    def kerker(self):
        w=1
    @classmethod
    def loss(self):
        print 123
    @staticmethod
    def wwww():
        print 123
```

and see its' id

```
print(id(Asian_loser.loss))
print(id(Asian_loser.kerker))
print(id(Asian_loser.wwww))
```

the loss and kerker method id will be the same and vary for a few seconds later

and I make a instance from Asian_loser

w=Asian_loser()

```
print(id(w.kerker))
print(id(w.loss))
print(id(w.wwww))
```

the loss and kerker method id will be the same and vary for a few seconds later

just want to know what accutally happen

Comment: The `id`s are not varying over time for me.

Comment: What Python version do you use?  The implementation details for this stuff went through some big changes between Python 2 and 3.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: It seems that Bound & unbound methods are almost temporary instance objects. will it get different result using python 3?

Comment: Probably.  The concept of a bound method doesn't really exist in Python 3.  In Python 2 methods are actually [descriptor objects](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11949808/674039) Q&A might help for you.

Comment: Hi wim , thx for you post . it's really helpful , maybe you can answer this question and thus I can close this question