# Unbound method error

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, self

I'm trying to understand the `self` keyword in python classes. Ergo I made up a simple class:

```
class Question(object):
    """A class for answering my OO questions about python.

       attributes: a_number"""

    def __init__():
        print "You've initialized a Question!"

    def myself_add(self, new_number):
        self.a_number += new_number
```

And in a `__main__` function below the class definition I'm running the code

```
my_q = Question
print my_q
my_q.a_number = 12
print 'A number:',my_q.a_number
my_q.myself_add(3)
print 'A number:',my_q.a_number
```

The result I'm getting (including error) is

```
<class '__main__.Question'>
A number: 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question.py", line 21, in <module>
    my_q.myself_add(3)
TypeError: unbound method myself_add() must be called with Question instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

I'm trying to understand why the method `myself_add` is considered unbound. What does that mean? And why doesn't it know that I'm calling it on an instance of the `Question` class? Also, why doesn't my `__init__` print happen?

Comment: in order to create an instance you should write `Question()`

Comment: also `__init__()` needs a `self` argument in it.

Comment: @PawełKordowski OMG, I can't believe it was that simple. Thanks! Throw that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to create an instance you need to write `Question()` not `Question`.

[`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) should take at least self argument

You may also want to initialize `self.a_number` in `__init__` or put in into the class body, otherwise the call of `myself_add` will fail if you do not execute `my_q.a_number = 12`

Answer (score 1):

The "self" argument can be anything, but is called self by convention.

It's passed in for you by python on default.

You can try running this simple code snippet to see what I mean:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def check(self, checked):
        print self is checked
```

and then from the command line:

```
a=A()
a.check(a)
```

You can take this further like this:

```
In [74]: b=A()

In [75]: a.check(b)
False
```

So here I've created two instances of A, one called a one called b. Only when comparing and instance of a's self to a itself is the statement true.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Specifically in your case, your class `Question` needs to be instantiated (`Question()`) and your `__init__` needs an argument (self by convention).

On when a function is bound, you might find this answer helpful:

[What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method) (but might be a bid advanced)

Comment: Great reference there, James. I'm used to languages where you have to syntactically differentiate class and instance methods, so that really cleared thing up a bit!

Answer (score 1):

First of all , when you initialize an instance of an class  you  use opening and closing parenthesis which calls the `__init__` method by convention.

```
my_q = Question()
```

However, in your case your `__init__` method is not bound to an object using `self`, so if you run as is it will give error,

```
    my_q = Question()
TypeError: __init__() takes no arguments (1 given)
>>>
```

You need to initialize `__init__` with `self` so that instance can make implicit call to the object.

```
def __init__(self):
```

Now , the program runs smoothly
First print is the `my_q` object itself.

```
>>> 
You've initialized a Question!
<__main__.Question object at 0x028ED2F0>
A number: 12
A number: 15
```