# How can I call a method stored in a variable?

Tags: python, class, methods

If I have a class `Foo` with the method `method1`, is there a way to store this method in a variable *before* instantiation, which I then could call *after* this class is instantiated?

For example:

```
class Foo:
    def method1(self, arg):
        print(self, arg)

# something like this variable, but which can be called with instantiated class 
func = Foo.method1

foo = Foo()
foo.func(1)  # I want to call it in a similar way to this
```

Comment: Oh, I never realized that methods behaved in that way for uninstantiated classes. This answers my question.

Comment: I'm planning to use this question as a duplicate target in the future, so I've touched it up a little to make it shorter and more to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, there is no real distinction between functions and methods - a method is merely a function defined in a class.

For us, this means that the function stored in the variable `func` can be called like any other function. If `func` refers to `Foo.method1`, it's a function with 2 parameters: `self` and `arg`. In order to invoke `func`, we simply pass a `Foo` instance as the `self` argument and another value as the `arg` argument:

```
func(foo, 1)
```

---

The reason why we usually don't have to pass an argument for `self` is because accessing the method through an instance automatically turns the *function* `method1` into a *bound method*, where the `self` argument is passed implicitly:

```
>>> Foo.method1  # Foo.method1 is a function
<function Foo.method1 at 0x7f9b3c7cf0d0>
>>>
>>> foo.method1  # but foo.method1 is a bound method!
<bound method Foo.method1 of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f9b3c7dd9e8>>
```

For more details about functions and methods, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11949808/1222951).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Rawing's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48412328/6573647) excellent answer, you may not need to instantiate the class if all you're accessing is a static or class attribute:

```
class Container:
    class_var = "class_var"
    def __init__(self, inst_var):
        self.inst_var = inst_var
        print("Instantiated")

    @staticmethod
    def static_mtd(static_arg):
        print(static_arg)

    def instance_mtd(self):
        print(self.inst_var)

    @classmethod
    def class_mtd(cls):
        print(cls.class_var)

stat = Container.static_mtd
stat("static_arg")  # static_arg

inst = Container.instance_mtd
inst(Container("inst_var"))   # Instantiated, inst_var

inst2 = Container("inst_var2").instance_mtd   # Instantiated
inst2()  # inst_var2

clas = Container.class_mtd
clas()  # class_var

var = Container.class_var # class_var
```

So, you can assign the variable name `inst` to an instance method `Container.instance_mtd` first, instantiate the `class` later on, and feed the instantiated `class` back into `inst` as the `self` argument. This is of course rather tedious, and it means that your reassigned instance method is effectively defined outside of the class.