# Safely bind method from one class to another class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, monkeypatching

I know I can attach a function to a class and make it a method:

```
 >>> def is_not_bound(inst, name):
...     print("Hello %s" % name)
... 
>>> 
>>> class NoMethods:
...     pass
... 
>>> 
>>> setattr(NoMethods, 'bound', is_not_bound)
>>> 
>>> NoMethods().bound("oz") # prints: Hello oz
Hello oz
```

To my surprise this works also with a bound method from one class to another:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def foo(self, name):
...         print("Hello %s" % name)
... 
>>> class B:
...     pass
... 
>>> setattr(B, 'bound_to_b', getattr(Foo, 'foo'))
>>> B().bound_to_b("confused?")
Hello confused?
>>>
```

Can I safely use this? Is there something I am overseeing?

#### update

One caveat that I found already:

```
>>> B.bound_to_b
<function Foo.foo at 0x7fc997e8b730>
```

Even though I called the method from B, It seems bound to Foo.

And even more surprising!:

```
>>> def new_method(self, addto):
...     return self.num + addto
... 
>>> setattr(B, 'add', new_method)
>>> b=B()
>>> b.num = 2
>>> b.add(2)
4
```

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with doing that. Python doesn't really have methods; a function defined in a class is still a function. (Assuming you're using python 3.)

Comment: Which part of the "even more surprising" code is surprising?

Comment: Actually, after reading it again, and seeing it's not Python 2, there is no bound or unboud. It's just a function. So, not surprisingly, it works!

Comment: methods are just the reference, you just used the same reference of the exiting function. what's confusing in here?

Comment: Can you please clarify what surprises you about that last block of code? It all makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: well, considering that is was new for me. It's surprising. Not confusing. I was suprised that it worked. I didn't expect Python to be that awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is an intended behavior (which is cool!). But also apparently, this behavior is not very familiar.

If you knew Python 2 for a long time, you would might not be aware of the fact that Python 3 has no methods (as commented above).

So in Python 3:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def foo(self, name):
...         print("Hello %s" % name)
... 
>>> Foo.foo
<function Foo.foo at 0x7f729a406730>
>>> def foo():
...     pass
... 
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x7f729b83ff28>
>>> 
>>> Foo.foo
<function Foo.foo at 0x7f729a406730>
```

There is no distinction! In Python 2 however:

```
Python 2.7.14 (default, Feb  2 2018, 02:17:12) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo:
...     def foo(self, name):
...         print("Hello %s" % name)
... 
>>> Foo.foo
<unbound method Foo.foo>
>>>
```

Comment: I don't see the point of this answer. All you've done is to repeat the things that have already been explained in [the question I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method). If _this_ answers your question, why not just mark the duplicate as accepted instead?

Comment: Because, people google this stuff, and the question you link answer also this question is titled differently.

Comment: Okay, but the answer in the other question still answers your question. What's the point of repeating it? If the question is marked as a duplicate, people can go read the original (and more complete) answer.

Comment: The point is that the accepted answer is talking about bound\unbound methods. Python 3 hasn't got those. It's a similar topic, but this question is much more specific.

Comment: I appreciate the emphasis that Python 2 is different from Python 3 on how methods are handled. This information may contribute to the solution of my current problem as I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure why my attempts to bind functions as methods isn't working - because there are no methods any more? I thought I'd forgotten all about Python 2 but maybe my mind is still polluted with it. However, this question and answer are a reall muddle with much that needs clarifying, as indicated by the comments. I wish someone could add a little detail to clarify.