# binding instance method of one class to another class

Tags: python, methods, function-binding

Consider the following case:

```py
class test:
  def foo(self, o):
    print(o)

  @staticmethod
  def bar(o):
    print(o)
    
  @classmethod
  def qux(cls, o):
    print(cls)
    print(o)

def baz(o):
  print(o)

t = test()

class A:
  meth1 = t.bar
  meth2 = t.foo
  meth3 = baz
  meth4 = t.qux

a = A()
a.meth1()
a.meth3()
# a.meth4()
# a.meth2()
```

This works just fine, but if I call `meth2/4` I get the following error:

`TypeError: <foo/qux>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'o'`

Is there any way I can get `t.foo` and `t.qux` working like `t.bar` and `baz`?

Answer (score 0):

`meth4` in `A` isn't being treated as a class method here because you have not defined it as such.

Class methods are declared using decorator syntax, like so:

```py
@decorator
def func(x, y):
    return z
```

which essentially defines a function `func` and then calls `decorator` on it.

Thus, you can actually just do `meth4 = classmethod(t.qux)`, and it works perfectly fine.

For `meth2`, I'm not sure what you expected to happen. It's an instance method that takes `self` implicitly and takes an argument `o`, so when you call `a.meth2`, of course you need to specify an argument `o`.

Comment: I expect `self` to be bound to `t`, and when `a.meth2` is called, it would bind `a` to `o`. I am basically looking for some way to automatically bind instance methods to the missing function parameter

Comment: @ntjess you could do `def meth2(self): t.foo(self)`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9NDoIwEIX3nGKWbWKaCKxMTOQoFdpIghTpkKiXrzOlVsXde29@vpnpgRc3ViG0g/Ye0Hg8FACdsWCdE94MdgdOcgYwzf2IwsmC3Mmjxr69Gprv0sRZz@Kvlw33R8BP@225i3bw2/0UyQ1uXf5Myz85wjGeLEivDzTcwJQ9lxRdlGCclfGfBEP1flCmkYpGiJJcTe7rZoGK7iWOprwhoFYRk1WVVZ1VSSqEFw "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Right, thanks. I was more curious about what makes all the other methods "auto-bind" where that doesn't happen here. I.e., what mechanism within Python causes `a` _not_ to be bound to `meth2`/`meth4`?

Comment: @ntjess This is part of the descriptor protocol, see [functions and methods](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods) in the documentation. Related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1015405/), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11950080/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49553252/). The key being in Python 3, `function` types get this treatment automatically, while other callable types (produced from `staticmethod`, `classmethod`, or simply callable class instances or classes) don't.

Comment: @ntjess The other ones don't actually bind. `meth1` works because calling `test.bar` on `a` sets the first argument, `o`, to `a`, because `a.b()` is just syntax for `type(a).b(a)`. `meth3` works for the same reason; calling `a.b()` just calls that function `b` but with the first argument being `a`, hence why instance methods usually call their first argument `self`.

Comment: @hyper-neutrino interesting, thanks for taking the time to explain. I was hoping that binding occurred on the already-bound version, not on the raw function. @metatoaster Does this mean I can add my own descriptor protocol to `test` for the desired result?

Comment: @metatoaster I am familiar with the difference between bound and unbound methods, but my mistake was thinking that function binding occurred somewhat like `functools.partial`. Thanks for the links