# Why is this false? `SomeClass.method is SomeClass.method`

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-descriptors

Take this code for example:

```
class SomeClass():
    def a_method(self):
        pass

print(SomeClass.a_method is SomeClass.a_method)     # Example 1: False
print(SomeClass.a_method == SomeClass.a_method)     # Example 2: True
print(SomeClass().a_method is SomeClass().a_method) # Example 3: False
print(SomeClass().a_method == SomeClass().a_method) # Example 4: False
```

- Example 1: I would have guessed that they were the same object. Does Python make a copy of the method each time it is referenced?
- Example 2: Expected.
- Example 3: Expected, since they are different objects.
- Example 4: Why doesn't this output match example 2?

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: I get True, True, False, False on py3

Comment: Python 2.7.14; sorry, will update.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11949808/1222951)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Example 1:

`Someclass.a_method` is an *unbound method*.  These don't even exist in Python nowadays, so consider this a useless history lesson.

> Does Python make a copy of the method each time it is referenced?

Yes, more or less.  This is done via [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

```
>>> SomeClass.a_method  # unbound method via attribute access
<unbound method SomeClass.a_method>
>>> SomeClass.__dict__['a_method']  # just stored as a function in the class dict
<function __main__.a_method>
>>> SomeClass.__dict__['a_method'].__get__(None, SomeClass)
<unbound method SomeClass.a_method>
```

The last line is showing the "binding" operation that descriptors invoke for attribute access on a class, but written out manually.  In pure Python, it's something like this

```
class Function(object):
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        return types.MethodType(self, obj, objtype):
```

You can also create a bound method that way:

```
>>> some_instance = SomeClass()
>>> SomeClass.__dict__['a_method'].__get__(some_instance, SomeClass)
<bound method SomeClass.a_method of <__main__.SomeClass instance at 0xcafef00d>>
```

#### Example 2:

Method comparison is done via the `__func__` and `__self__` attributes on the methods.  In this case, they are both identical: the `__func__` is the same plain old function you can dig out of the class dict, and the `__self__` is `None`.  So despite these methods being different objects, they compare equal.

#### Example 3:

Correct.  They are different objects, and hence not identical.

#### Example 4:

As mentioned earlier, comparison is using the `__func__` and `__self__` attributes.  The result doesn't match example 2 because, in this case, the `__self__` attributes are referring to different instances.  Those different instances don't compare equal because `SomeClass` instances compare by identity, therefore the methods also don't compare equal.

## A final note on the current version of Python

Everything mentioned above applies to the current version of the language, too, except for **Example 1**.  In Python, there is no longer such thing as an unbound method, this unnecessary complication in the object model was removed.

```
>>> SomeClass.a_method
<function __main__.SomeClass.a_method(self)>
>>> SomeClass.a_method is SomeClass.__dict__['a_method']
True
```

What was an "unbound method" in Python 2 is now just a plain old function, and the instance retrieved via attribute access is identical to the object in the class dict.  The **Example 1** result changes from `False` to `True` in a Python 2 -> Python 3 upgrade.