# Different ways of unioning sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) suggests two ways to union sets:

```
set1 = {1, 2, 3}
set2 = {3, 4, 5}

set1 | set2       # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
set1.union(set2)  # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

I've recently come across yet another one:

```
set.union(set1, set2)  # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

How does it work?

Comment: set.union(set1,set2) is semantically equivalent to  set1.union(set2). See the documentation on python objects.

Comment: `set.union` uses the `set.union` method with `set1` being the `self` argument and `set2` being the second argument. It is essentially equivalent to `set1.union(set2)`. In python, `my_instance.some_method(arg)` is equivalent (essentially but not exactly) to `MyClass.some_method(my_instance, arg)`

Comment: Note that the arguments can be any iterable, e.g. `set().union([1,2,3], (2, 3, 4)) -> {1, 2, 3, 4}`

Comment: You've just discovered [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors) in [method binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765186/674039).

Comment: Here's yet another syntax to add to your collection:  `{*set1, *set2}`

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `set.union(set1, set2)` actually calls the `union` method with `set1` for the `self` argument. Therefore, it is equivalent to `set1.union(set2)`.

As an aside, Python allows union-ing of arbitrary numbers of sets according to [this](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/set/union). Actually you can see this in the Python documentation, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set). Because the `union` method accepts `*others` as an argument, you can pass in any number of sets and it will perform the union of all of them.

```
set1 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
set2 = {1, 3, 4, 5}
set3 = {2, 4, 6, 7}

print(set.union(set1, set2, set))
# {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but the fact that union allows arbitrary number of sets is not relevant here (you would see the same behaviour if it was only accepting one other).

Comment: @wim In all honesty, I thought the OP had created a third set called `set` and was calling `union` with `set` as the `self` argument, in which case this would've been valid information. On further inspection, that wasn't the case. However, his question concerns the ways `union` can be called so I think my the first part of my answer was relevant, albeit tangential