# Why the diffent class instance have same id in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am try to get diffent instance of one class in mutil-thread, but the id(instance) retuned the same id random, Even if I add sleep time, this still happens, why?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding=utf-8

import random
import threading

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = random.randrange(10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return "rand num is {}".format(self.num)

def getInatance():
    if lock.acquire():
        f = Foo()
        print(id(f), f)
        lock.release()

lock = threading.Lock()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for x in range(10):
        th = threading.Thread(target=getInatance)
        th.start()

    for th in threading.enumerate():
        if th is not threading.current_thread():
            th.join()

# 2384808866048 rand num is 357
# 2384808640128 rand num is 7143
# 2384808640128 rand num is 900
# 2384808640128 rand num is 3260
# 2384808640032 rand num is 8161
# 2384808640032 rand num is 8573
# 2384808640080 rand num is 6300
# 2384808640080 rand num is 3476
# 2384808640128 rand num is 8112
# 2384808640128 rand num is 7357
```

Comment: The method probably returns faster than a new thread can be initialized, and as a result the runtime ends up reusing the same addresses. Try adding `sleep(1)` before `lock.release()`

Comment: Useful background here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034033/id-getattribute-function-returned-different-value-when-getattr-method-d/53034800 Note: *"The values you get from id are guaranteed to be unique, but only among objects that exist at the same time"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`id(f)` is only guaranteed to give you a unique id amog all objects that are currently alive. But your code is structured so it's quite unlikely that more than one `Foo` instances are alive at the same time.

Your `getInatance()` function serializes creating the `Foo` instances, and once the `getInatance()` function returns, the `Foo` instance you created is destroyed, and the next object you create may get the same id as a prior object that doesn't exist any more.

If you add a `sleep()` as shown below you are more likely to see unique object IDs. (But still no guarantees - and remember that adding sleep() to fix apparent multithreading problems is wrong).

```
def getInatance():
    if lock.acquire():
        f = Foo()
        print(id(f), f)
        lock.release()
    time.sleep(1)
```