# how parameters are passed around inside `__getattr__`

Tags: python, python-3.x, delegates

I understand the basic function and use case of `__getattr__` method. But I'm having trouble how parameters are passed around inside `__getattr__`.

I have code

```
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, object):
        self.wrapped = object
    def __getattr__(self, attrname):
        print('trace: ' + attrname)
        return getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)


x = Wrapper([1, 2, 3])
x.append(4)
print(x.wrapped)
```

And it prints

```
trace: append
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Forgive me if my assumption below is incorrect. I assume that the parameter `4` in `x.append(4)` is somehow passed from the initial call to `__getattr__` and then to the call to `getattr` method and then to the `append` method of `list` class. But I'm not sure what exactly is happening. Could someone please clarify the details.

Comment: What? Neither `__getattr__` nor `getattr` ever come in contact with that `4`. 4 isn't an attribute, after all.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I understand that `4` is not an attribute, but I was just wondering how is the original argument `4` passed to the call to `append` method of `list` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I understand it:

```py
x = Wrapper([1, 2, 3])
```

So, `x.wrapped` is a `list`, that is `[1, 2, 3]`.

Now, when you do `x.append`, you call `__getattr__`  of `Wrapper`, with argument `append`. So when python resolves:

```py
getattr(self.wrapped, attrname)
```

it gets the method `append` of your inner list, which is then returned. So, you could imagine that your code is interpreted as:

```py
# just got it outside for later explanation
l = [1, 2, 3]

x = Wrapper(l)

f = x.__getattr__('append')
# here `f` is the `append` method of `l`

f(4) # which is equivalent to `l.append(4)`

# finally
print(x.wrapped)
# which is equivalent to `print(l)`, hence the output
# [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: hi Houdin, thank for the answer. It definitely helps me better visualise the process. Just wondering if you know any official documentation that document the process?

Comment: Well... You have python's [official documentation for `__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__), but apart from this link, I don't really know...

Comment: I have already checked the official documentation for __getattr__ but it doesn't seem to contain the info I'm looking for. Thanks for helping out! really appreciate it :)

Comment: I have found this [link](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) about python's resolution order of methods. It's actually for python 2.3, but I guess it doesn't differ a lot from the one used in 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

`__getattr__` never comes in contact with that `4`. `__getattr__` simply returns a bound method, which is then called with the argument `4`. *Obtaining* the bound method and *calling* the bound method are two unrelated steps, and `__getattr__` is only responsible for the first one.

It might be easier to follow along if you mentally split this line:

```
x.append(4)
```

into two:

```
method = x.append  # obtain the bound method
method(4)          # call the bound method
```

Clearly, `__getattr__` is called in the first line and has nothing to do with the 2nd line. `__getattr__` simply returns a reference to the `append` method of the wrapped list, as you can easily verify for yourself:

```
>>> x.append
<built-in method append of list object at 0x7f096feb2fc8>
```

This is a *bound method*. A bound method is simply a method that has a reference to the object that will take the place of the `self` when the method is called (in this case, the list `x.wrapped`). Bound methods are the reason why we can call methods without explicitly passing an argument for `self`.

For more details about bound methods, see [What is the difference between a function, an unbound method and a bound method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method).