# Get class method reference into dict

Tags: python

Why output is:

```
<class 'method'>                                                                                                                    
<class 'method'>                                                                                                                        
<class 'function'>                                                                                                                      
<class 'function'>
```

not

```
<class 'method'>                                                                                                                         
<class 'method'>
<class 'method'>                                                                                                                                <class 'method'>
```

#### Code

```
class A:

    def ftest(self, a, *args):
        b = args[0]
        self.r = a+b

f_ref = ftest

f_dict = {
    'ftest': ftest,
    'f_ref': f_ref
}

inst = A()

print(type(inst.ftest))
print(type(inst.f_ref))

print(type(inst.f_dict['ftest']))
print(type(inst.f_dict['f_ref']))
```

I've made a funtion routing cmd args and type 'function' instead 'method' causes exceptions (I'm not passing self, I don't know whether variable is function or function pointing to method).

Comment: Because a method is an object that binds a  function to an instance, but the functions in the class are just functions unless they are accessed via the instance, where they become bound methods

Comment: So Is there a way to check if function (which is a method) expects `self` as argument?

Comment: Is there only one instance? How would you know otherwise? Just use `my_instance.my_method` and pass *that*, it will have the instance bound, which is what you need.

Comment: @bajos: `self` is purely by convention, and unbound methods are plain functions, indistinguishable from any other function not defined within a class.

Answer (score 0):

The first two are **bound** methods and the last two are **unbound** methods. In the end, all are *functions*, the only difference is that bound methods receives the associated instance object as first parameter (self):

```
class A:

  def __init__(self, p):
    self.p = p

  def print_p(self):
    print(self.p)

a = A(10)

a.print_p() # This is equivalent
A.print_p(a) # to this
```

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method/11950331) for more info

Comment: In Python 3, there are no unbound methods. Just functions, but yes.

Comment: Adding to @juanpa.arrivillaga: This is why the OP's goal isn't really possible; unless accessed via a class instance, the "methods" are just plain functions, same as a function defined outside of a class, so you can't tell the difference between a "maybe method" and a "pure function".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, I just said **unbound methods** to diferentiate them from _standard_ functions, but you are right.

Comment: @JosuéCortina well *exactly*, there *is no distinction in Python 3*.