# When using python function do you have to understand a descriptor

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback

I got some confusion with the following pygatt code example regarding a python function call. In the end: when you see a function call in python code it could well be a bound-method being called on an instance of another object. This can be achieved by passing the bound-method to a variable, and you call the variable as a function.

This seems hard for human to be aware of. For python coders, do you have to check every function call whether it is a bound-method when you read python code? As I read about bound-method is a descriptor, do you have to understand the whole descriptor concept to under a piece of python code?

Is that the right direction and is that all?

---

Below is the long story how it got me to ask this question.

So I asked "python use instance method as callback function - how to get a reference to the instance for the class for the method" here regarding my initial confusion with the following code snippet.

The triggering point was regarding the `scan_cb` callback in pygatt library. An illustration can be:

```
class BGLibBackend:
    def __init__(self):
        self._scan_cb = None
    def set_cb(self, scan_cb):
        self._scan_cb = scan_cb
    def service(self):
        if self._scan_cb is not None:
            self._scan_cb(...)

class UserApp:
    def user_cb(theobj, ...):
        .....when it reaches here, how to get the self that is an instance of UserAPP ? 
    def __init__(self):
        self._bg = BGLibBackend()
        self._bg.set_cb(self.user_cb):
```

It looked to me when the method callback `user_cb()` is called, the first argument `thisobj` appeared to be a reference to the caller instance, that would be an instance of `BGLibBackend`. However with hints in the comments, it turned out to be an instance of `UserApp`.

To this point, I wondered whether calling a normal function and a bound-method will have exactly same effect, or whether you have to know about some more rules so as to deal with them differently.

From a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method/26943327), it looks I'll need to understand the descriptor concept behind a function. Probably that will solve my concern. But I'm also wondering whether there is more than a descriptor, or whether descriptor is a wrong direction to understanding this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Should ``theobj`` be ``self`` (an instance of ``UserApp``) or ``self._bg`` ("instance of ``BGLibBackend``")? Are you aware that ``UserApp().user_cb``/``self.user_cb`` already binds the instance as the first argument?

Comment: The `theobj` should be `self` as an instance of `UserApp` where it is passed to the `set_cb()`. Googled `python bound method vs function` and it came up [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method/26943327). Not sure ... let's say: A bound-method can be passed to a variable. When that variable is called, it appears exactly the same as a simple function. It could hide the fact that the function call can be on an instance of another class. That is kind weird ... . Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Ok, the `theobj` is already what I wanted in the original question. Now this bound-method when being called, is it really exactly the same as a normal function? Any

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in one. If you want to know about other things, open a new question.

Comment: Ok, I'll change the questions asked by this post. Thanks.