# Why is QtCore.Signal in pyside6 called at different memory addresses in different classes?

Tags: python, signals, pyside6, qtcore

this is my code.

```
from PySide6 import QtCore

class MyClass(QtCore.QObject):
    my_signal = QtCore.Signal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class Myclass2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c1 = MyClass()
        print(2, id(self.c1.my_signal))

class Myclass3():
    def __init__(self):
        self.c1 = MyClass()
        print(3, id(self.c1.my_signal))


c1 = MyClass()
print(1, id(c1.my_signal))
c2 = Myclass2()
c3 = Myclass3()
```

this is output of the code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZMCe.png)

1.Why do different instantiated classes have different my_signal memory addresses?

Comment: Why do you expect them to share the same memory address? A signal can only be emitted by an instance, and it has to be specific to that instance. Signals are unbound for classes, and become bound to instances (see the [PyQt docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#unbound-and-bound-signals)).

Comment: because my_signal is a class attribute, it shared by all instances of the class. so I assume there is the same memory address.

Comment: @SLF But it ***is*** the same: `print(type(c1).my_signal is type(c2.c1).my_signal is type(c3.c1).my_signal)` -> `True`. Your example code doesn't compare like with like. Every instance creates its own bound-signal object so the signal-slot mechanism can distinguish between senders (e.g. consider APIs like [QObject.sender()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#sender)). Signals work exactly like [bound and unbound methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11949808/984421), since they need access to `self` (i.e. they're [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)).

Comment: @SLF Just because an object is created as a class attribute it doesn't make it "immutable" to all its instances. For example: `MyClass().someFuntion != MyClass().someFuntion`. Also, [please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).