# Converting im_class in python 2.7 to python 3.8

Tags: python

I am converting some python 2.7 code to work with python 3.8. One thing I am stuck on is how to get a reference to im_class working. The original code looks like this:

```
class UpdateDbQueue():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.job = kwargs["job"]
        self.method = self.job
        self.cls = self.job.im_class
        self.name = "{}.{}".format(self.cls.__name__, self.method.__name__)
```

Running a debugger shows that kwargs["job"] equals `<function DateRange.get_events at 0x112f84f80>`. The python2to3 utility converted the code to this:

```
class UpdateDbQueue():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.job = kwargs["job"]
        self.method = self.job
        self.cls = self.job.__self__.__class__
        self.name = "{}.{}".format(self.cls.__name__, self.method.__name__)
```

Which returns an error:

```
self.cls = self.job.__self__.__class__
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__self__'
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I tried changed it simple to self.job.**class** but got an error `KeyError: 'DateRange.get_events'`.

Edit - this is a snipped of the DateRange class.

class DateRange(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.DateTime, primary_key=True)

```
def get_events(self, rows=10000):
    # gets events from database

def __repr__(self):
    return "<DateRange (starts: {})>".format(self.id)
```

Comment: Did you try the original? `self.cls = self.job.im_class` instead? What is `DateRange`? What is `DateRange.getevents`? Do either have an `im_class` attribute?

Comment: @wwii `im_class` is part of the data model for a bounded method in python2 https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html

Comment: Yes I tried the original but got: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'im_class'`. I will update the code with DateRange.

Comment: How do you call `UpdateDbQueue` and pass the `job` attribute? Based on your last update, it should be something like `UpdateDbQueue(job=DateRange().get_events)`

Comment: It is called with `update_registry.register(UpdateDbQueue(
    job=DateRange.get_events,
    action_table="date_range"
))`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25959545/2823755

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `im_class` attribute is found in an [unbounded method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949808/what-is-the-difference-between-a-function-an-unbound-method-and-a-bound-method) in python2:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.16 (default, Nov  9 2019, 05:55:08) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.32.4) (-macos10.15-objc-s'
>>> class S:
...    def f(s):
...      pass
...
>>> 'im_class' in dir(S.f)
True
```

Since unbounded methods are not a thing in python3, this does not exist in this type of object anymore:

```
In [9]: sys.version
Out[9]: '3.7.3 (default, Nov 15 2019, 04:04:52) \n[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]'

In [10]: class S:
    ...:     def f(s):
    ...:         pass
    ...:

In [11]: 'im_class' in dir(S.f)
Out[11]: False
```

The python2to3 conversion tool seems to be assuming you have a *bounded* method in python3:

```
In [12]: sys.version
Out[12]: '3.7.3 (default, Nov 15 2019, 04:04:52) \n[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]'

In [13]: class S:
    ...:     def f(s):
    ...:         pass
    ...:

In [14]: '__self__' in dir(S().f) ## bounded by S()
Out[14]: True
```

However this does not look like a bounded method based on your information about `kwargs['job']`

> Running a debugger shows that kwargs["job"] equals `<function DateRange.get_events at 0x112f84f80>`

which is just a plain function, which is what unbounded methods are in python3.

One thing to try is to bind the function to a local method using [`types`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType) after assigning to an instance which could have been the intent:

```
import types
class UpdateDbQueue():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.job = types.MethodType(kwargs['job'], self)
```

This way you have the necessary attributes:

```
In [26]: def f(s):
    ...:     pass
    ...:

In [27]: class S:
    ...:     def __init__(self):
    ...:         self.f = types.MethodType(f, self)
    ...:         if '__self__' in dir(self.f):
    ...:             print("I have __self__")
    ...:
    ...:

In [28]: S()
I have __self__
Out[28]: <__main__.S at 0x111711dd8>
```

However `job` needs to expect to be called as a bounded method (so the instance is passed as the first argument, etc)

#### Edit:

Based on your question edit, seems that if you were calling this class with the appropriate bounded method, it should work, so how are you calling the `UpdateDbQueue` class?

Comment: The command is run with this: update_registry.register(UpdateDbQueue(
    job=DateRange.get_events,
    action_table="date_range"
)).

Comment: … I think `self.cls = self.job.__class__` would be correct then.

Comment: @wwii not because a plain function's (an unbounded method in py3)  `__class__` is `function` not `DateRange` as desired.

Comment: @Casey can you change to calling the class like this `DateRane().get_events`