# Initialize all the classes in a module into nameless objects in a list

Tags: python, oop

Is there a way to initialize all classes from a python module into a list of nameless objects?

**Example**
I have a module `rules` which contains all child classes from a class Rule. Because of that, I'm certain they will all implement a method `run()` and will have a attribute `name` which will be generated during the call of `__init__`

I would like to have a list of objects dynamically initiated from those classes. By dynamically initialized i mean that they don't have to be named explicitly.

The questions are:

Is it possible to iterate through all classes in a module?

Can a nameless object be initiated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are at least two approaches you can take.  You can get all of the subclasses of a class by calling a class's `__subclasses__()` method.  So if your parent class is called `Rule`, you could call:

```
rule_list = [cls() for cls in Rule.__subclasses__()]
```

This will give you all subclasses of `Rule`, and will not limit them to the ones found in a particular module.

If you have a handle to your module, you can iterate over its content.  Like so:

```
import rule
rule_list = []
for name in dir(rule):
    value = getattr(rule, name)
    if isinstance(value, type) and issubclass(value, Rule):
        rule_list.append(value())
```

Unfortunately, `issubclass` throws `TypeError` if you give it an object that is not a class as its first argument.  So you have to handle that somehow.

EDIT: dealing with the `issubclass` quirk per @Blckknght's suggestion.

Comment: Better than my answer. You can use `inspect.isclass()` to avoid the `TypeError`.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides True, you can use `inspect.isclass()` as a filter.  I try to avoid using anything from the `inspect` module in production code, however.

Comment: You can also use `isinstance(value, type)` to make sure you have a class. (You'd also need to check for `types.ClassType` if you need to support old-style classes, but I'd just avoid those instead.)