# Ignore imported functions in a python module when using getmembers(module, isfunction)

Tags: python, reflection

Is there a way to ignore imported functions in a python module?

When using the following module module.py:

```
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction
import foo

def boo():
   foo()

def moo():
   pass


funcs = [mem[0] for mem in getmembers(module, isfunction)]
```

funcs equals : `['boo','moo', 'foo']` (including imported function 'foo')

I want funcs to include `['boo', 'moo']` only.

Comment: See the top answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520580/how-do-you-get-all-classes-defined-in-a-module-but-not-imported). It looks like if you filter by `__module__` you can filter out the imports.

Comment: Be warned: modules often have parts of their public API written in and imported from other modules. For example, most of `heapq` actually comes from `_heapq`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to test for the `__module__` attribute; it is a string naming the full module path:

```
funcs = [mem[0] for mem in getmembers(module, isfunction)
         if mem[1].__module__ == module.__name__]
```