# Best way to instantiate classes which is in imported modules

Tags: python

I have class `A` inside module `consumers\a`, `B` inside `consumers\a` and `C` inside `consumers\c`.  I have used the following code to fetch the classes. Is there any other way to achieve the same. (this will work only if the `class_name.lower() == module_name`).

```
    bridge.py

    import inspect
    import types

    from consumers import a
    from consumers import b
    from consumers import c

    for name, val in globals().items():
    if isinstance(val, types.ModuleType):
        if 'consumers' in val.__name__:
            for k, v in inspect.getmembers(val):
                if k.lower() == name:
                    v()
```

I am trying this because I don't want the successor to do lot of work to add consumer.

I read,
[how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796180/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-classes-within-current-module-in-python), /[how-do-you-get-all-classes-defined-in-a-module-but-not-imported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520580/how-do-you-get-all-classes-defined-in-a-module-but-not-imported) and few more links and came up with the above solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is this a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just import:

```
from consumers.a import A
from consumers.b import B
from consumers.C import C

a = A()
b = B()
c = C()
```

Comment: @JohnPrawyn with that many, I'd be inclined to put them in a list. Could you move the classes into a sub-module, and expose the list via `__init__.py`?