# How to find the names of classes inside a python module?

Tags: python

If I import a module:

```
import foo
```

How can I find the names of the classes it contains?

Comment: are you just trying to learn how to use the class or are you looking for something like a `list` of names?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module to do this.  For example:

```
import inspect
import foo

for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(foo):
    if inspect.isclass(obj):
        print name
```

Comment: I got only __class__ as output, not the real class name

Comment: Well I'm not sure why that would be, it works fine for me, both with standard library modules and ones I've written myself (with python 2.7)

Answer (score 3):

Check in `dir(foo)`.  By convention, the class names will be those in CamelCase.

If `foo` breaks convention, you could I guess get the class names with something like `[x for x in dir(foo) if type(getattr(foo, x)) == type]`, but that's ugly and probably quite fragile.

Answer (score 1):

From the question [How to check whether a variable is a class or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395735/python-how-to-check-whether-a-variable-is-a-class-or-not) we can check if a variable is a class or not with the `inspect` module (example code shamelessly lifted from the accepted answer):

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class X(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> inspect.isclass(X)
True
```

So to build a list with all the classes from a module we could use

```
import foo
classes = [c for c in dir(foo) if inspect.isclass(getattr(foo, c))]
```

**Update:** The above example has been edited to use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr)`(foo, c)` rather than use `foo.__getattribute__(c)`, as per **@Chris Morgan**'s comment.

Comment: Your second example doesn't work.  c just contains a string of the name of the class, inspect.isclass expects an object.

Comment: You shouldn't do `foo.__getattribute__(c)`. You should do `getattr(foo, c)`.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan. Ok, but why is that?

Comment: You should only ever call `__magic__` methods where it's absolutely necessary, and generally only on `self`; the wrappers are the proper interface for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type of elements found via `dir(foo)`: classes will have type `type`.

```
import foo
classlist = []
for i in dir(foo):
    if type(foo.__getattribute__(i)) is type:
        classlist.append(i)
```

Comment: I got only __class__ as output, not the real class name

Comment: You shouldn't do `foo.__getattribute__(c)`. You should do `getattr(foo, c)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a lot of information about a Python module, say foo, by importing it and then using help(module-name) as follows:

```
>>> import foo 
>>> help(foo)
```