# How to list gdb python module elements by different types?

Tags: python, gdb

I use this to show the items of the python gdb module in the gdb (GNU debugger).

```
gdb -q -nh <<-EOF
python
import gdb
print('\n'.join(dir(gdb)))
EOF
```

But it does not classify the times as classes, functions and data. The following command can show the whole help page, which include classes, functions and data. Is there a way to just list the class names (ignoring the builtin class names), the function names and the data names, respectively?

```
gdb -q -nh <<-EOF
python
import gdb
print(help(gdb))
EOF
```

Comment: Looks like that you *actually* want this instead [How can I use IPython interactive shell in gdb? | How can I get tab-completion to work in gdb's Python-interactive (pi) shell? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231270/how-can-i-use-ipython-interactive-shell-in-gdb-how-can-i-get-tab-completion-t/70241082#70241082) (my question)

Comment: Still, for the question itself, yes it's possible and it's not specific to gdb, see [How do I detect whether a Python variable is a function? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function) and [python - How to check whether a variable is a class or not? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395735/how-to-check-whether-a-variable-is-a-class-or-not)