# Python: Test if an argument is a type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to check if an argument is a type class. Not if an argument is of a specific type like int, but that is a type.

Here's some code illustrating what I want to achieve:

```
def is_type(arg):
    if arg is a type:
        return True
    return False


is_type(int) # true
is_type(str) # true
is_type(23) # false
is_type(type(23)) # true
```

What should the body of `is_type` be to achieve this? I tried `if arg is type:` but that's didn't work.

Comment: I don't know who has closed your question with inappropriate duplicate. But the answer is also found here on SO. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395735/how-to-check-whether-a-variable-is-a-class-or-not

Comment: @sudden_appearance Yeah, clearly they didn't read my question. However you did and linked a correct answer, so thanks!